# Matillion grid variables can not be use in a transformation job in the sql component

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, matillion

I'm using a query result to grid component, to transform a select into grid variables.

After I'm connecting with  a transformation job using a grid iterator Sequential.

The following select provide me empty string

SELECT DISTINCT
'${column_validated}'
FROM '${table_name}'

I try to figure out why the grid variables in a select are empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.